# How to enable JSR-303 bean validation in Facelets?

Tags: spring, facelets, bean-validation

I'm using spring CDI and a customized "View" scope. (See [this](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) about how it works.)

The view bean is annotated with JSR-303 validation rules as following:

```
@Scope("view")
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    String message;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10)
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void action1() {
        ...
    }

}
```

And the user form:

```
...
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:inputText name="message" value="${myBean.message}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Update" actionListener="${myBean.action1}" />
</h:form>
```

However, the validation doesn't work. Am I missing something in `faces-config.xml`? I guess there should be some proxy classes involved in, which maybe generated by AspectJ weaver or so. Right?

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @dar-whi: I'm using Facelets indeed. I guess it's JSF 2.x.

Comment: Facelets already existed before JSF 2.x -> the question is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSR 303 validation for JSF is auto enabled if you add implementation jar to classpath.